# Visual Studio Cordova build fails

Tags: android, node.js, visual-studio-cordova

When I build any android app with Cordova, it fails with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepEnv' of undefined.

I've done all the troubleshooting and checked environment variables (As per MS documentation)

What I found is that if I call `bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build --ant --debug` from my project folder, the build works.

But when I call `"C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli.cmd"   build --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --rojectName Gappy --npmInstallDir C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US --buildTarget AndroidDevice`, the build fails.

One of the steps of the second method, is to call the first batch file.

This happens with VS2013 and VS2015. 64 and 32 bit versions of Node.JS

Any help / ideas?

Comment: Can you post the diagnostic build log. 
Go to Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, change MSBuild project "Build Output Verbosity" to Diagnostic. 
After you rebuild the project - there should hopefully be extra information - that might help you solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same error with this output :

Comment: >command: D:\cordova\build.bat --debug --ant
>D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
>throw e;
>^
>TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepEnv' of undefined
> at Object.module.exports.run (D:\cordova\lib\build.js:326:19)
> at D:\cordova\build:36:22
> at _fulfilled (D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
> at self.promiseDispatch.done (D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
> at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
> at D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:574:44
> at flush (D:\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)

Comment: In my last comment, I edited the output to fit the max char count.  I changed the path from D:\CS.Cordova\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova to D:\cordova

Comment: I get the same error.

Comment: BTW, it used to work for me with CTP 3, but I get the error since I uninstalled and installed CTP 3.1

Comment: Go into bld/Debug/platforms/android/cordova and type "version".  If the version reported is less than 3.6.4, go to the bld/Debug folder and type "cordova platform remove android" and then "cordova platform add android@3.6.4" and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: my version was already 3.6.4, so it looks like that's not the problem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I noticed that the build file is called differnetly depending on whether the path to the solution contains spaces:

1>  ------ Build configuration options:
1>  Running command: C:\Projects\Mobile\AppSolutionName\AppSolutionName\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug --ant

1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Projects\Mobile Apps\AppSolutionName\AppSolutionName\bld\Debug\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant ""

It works if there are spaces and it fails with "TypeError: Cannot read property 'prepEnv' of undefined" if there are none. I don't know if this is specific to my environment but with the spaces in the path I can build now.

Comment: Wow, this works!  You just unblocked me, thanks!  I have filled this bug : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1192337/tools-for-apache-cordova-ctp-3-1-cant-build-for-android

Comment: Took me two hours to figure it out but I didn't have the time to dig any further. Glad I could be of help and let's hope it gets fixed.

Comment: I'm marking this as a solution until the bug is fixed at connect.

Comment: To elaborate on this:

Simply put...

c:\source\folder\whatever\something\blah\...  == BAD BAD BAD

c:\source code\folder\whatever\something\blah\... == GOOD GOOD GOOD  (note the space in "source code").  Doesn't matter where...just make sure there's a space somewhere

Basically it's just like at a command prompt.  If you have spaces in your path ANYWHERE...it will put double quotes around it causing it to WORK.

If you don't have any spaces anywhere in your path...no double quotes...no workie.

Thanks for days of wasted time Microsoft.  How about a quick little SCRUM with your QA dept eh?

Comment: Great answer , thanks! but doesn't work without spaces in the path? really? gives me great confidence in this framework

Comment: so it has come to this.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X Yosemite:

Cleaning the project and rebuilding it with sudo fixed it for me.

On **/path/to/your/project**/platforms/android/cordova folder:

```
sudo ./clean
sudo ./build --release
```